# Multiple icons shown on launcher

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, ubuntu

After upgrade from Tor Browser from 7.X to 8.0 I now have two Tor Browser icons on the launcher. How can I remove one of them?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Additional info: the top one does not respond to clicks (should bring to foreground)

both disappear when Tor Browser is closed (expected)

EDITTED: the desktop file contains the line

```
Icon=/INSTALL_LOCATION/Tor Browser/Browser/browser/icons/mozicon128.png
```

but the `png` does not exist (it used to exist in 7.X)

Manually changing to

```
Icon=/INSTALL_LOCATION/Tor Browser/Browser/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
```

fixes it temporarily (once I use the desktop file the change is gone)

***How can I make this change permanently?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bud 26556 fixed: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/26556

> I use the Tor Browser alpha on GNU/Linux having installed it with ./start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app long ago. The .desktop points to the icon being in Browser/browser/icons/mozicon128.png, but the Browser/browser/icons/ directory doesn't seem to exist anymore with the upgrade to 8.0a9.
>
> mozicon128.png can't be found anywhere in the bundle at all, and this keeps the launcher from showing the icon after the upgrade.